# Convert an array of CChar to Hexa String in Swift

Tags: swift, string

i have an array of **CChar**

```
var buff = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: 10)
```

and i want to convert array of **CChar to String**. 
I tried the following way,

```
let string = String(bytes: buff, encoding: .utf8)
```

but it gives me the error : `Initializer 'init(bytes:encoding:)' requires the types 'CChar' (aka 'Int8') and 'UInt8' be equivalent`

**Note: the resulted string is expected to be a hexa string**

any help is appreciated.

----------------------ADDITIONAL INFO ------------------------------

actually i am porting my changes from *Java* to *Swift*, (Android to iOS)
i am reading some http traffic as bytes, and so the *buff* is obviously contain the read bytes.

resulting Array buff may be:

```
buff[CChar] = [56, 54, 45, -103, 95, -59]
```

Comment: `String(bytes:encoding:)` is the equivalent of `String(data:encoding:)` but it expects a sequence of bytes `[UInt8]` instead of a `Data` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Swift [cString initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641523-init):

```
init(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>)
```

---

> If cString contains ill-formed UTF-8 code unit sequences, this
>   initializer replaces them with the Unicode replacement character
>   ("\u{FFFD}").

---

```
let buff: [CChar] = [97, 98, 99, 0] // null-terminated string 
let string: String = .init(cString: buff) 
print(string)    // "abc\n"
```

---

**edit/update:**

To convert from [CChar] to hexaString you would need to map your bitPattern and use String format: "%02x" to convert the bytes to hexa:

```
let buff: [CChar] = [56, 54, 45, -103, 95, -59]
let hexaString = buff.map {
    String(format: "%02x", UInt8(bitPattern: $0))
}.joined()

print(hexaString)  // "38362d995fc5\n"
```

Comment: i get error says: Ambiguous reference to member 'init'

Comment: actually the CChar[] to string should give a "hexa String",